# Questions about the Ferrara-Zumino Multiplet

Tags: supersymmetry, supergravity, superspace-formalism

These questions arose while reading the paper ``[Comments on Supercurrent Multiplets, Supersymmetric Field Theories and Supergravity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.2228)" by Komargodski and Seiberg ([arXiv:1002.2228](https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.2228))

The Ferrara-Zumino multiplet is defined by the equations

\begin{align}
    {\overline{D}}^{\dot{\alpha}} \mathcal{J}_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}} &= D_{\alpha}X\\
    {\overline{D}}^{\dot{\alpha}} X &= 0
 \end{align}

and is subject to the improvement transformations

\begin{align}\label{eq:improvement}
 \begin{split}
   \mathcal{J}_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}' &= \mathcal{J}_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}} - i\partial_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}(\Xi - \overline{\Xi}) = \mathcal{J}_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}} + [D_{\alpha}, \overline{D}_{\dot{a}}](\Xi + \overline{\Xi})\\
   X' &= X + \frac{1}{2}{\overline{D}}^2\overline{\Xi}\\
   \overline{D}_{\dot{\alpha}} \Xi &= 0
 \end{split}
\end{align}

The claim is that these transformations preserve the form of the Ferrara-Zumino equation. But I'm a bit puzzled by this:

\begin{align}
\overline{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}\mathcal{J}_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}' &= \overline{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}\left(\mathcal{J}_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}} + [D_{\alpha}, \overline{D}_{\dot{\alpha}}](\Xi + \overline{\Xi})\right)\\
   &= D_{\alpha} X + \overline{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}[D_{\alpha}, \overline{D}_{\dot{\alpha}}](\Xi + \overline{\Xi})\\
   &= D_{\alpha} X + \overline{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}(D_{\alpha} \overline{D}_{\dot{\alpha}}\overline{\Xi} - \overline{D}_{\dot{\alpha}}D_{\alpha}\Xi)\\
   &= D_{\alpha} X + \overline{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}D_{\alpha} \overline{D}_{\dot{\alpha}}\overline{\Xi} - \overline{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}\overline{D}_{\dot{\alpha}}D_{\alpha}\Xi\\
   &= D_{\alpha} X - \overline{D}_{\dot{\alpha}}D_{\alpha}\overline{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}\overline{\Xi} + \overline{D}_{\dot{\alpha}}\overline{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}D_{\alpha}\Xi\\
   &= D_{\alpha} X - (\{\overline{D}_{\dot{\alpha}}, D_{\alpha}\}-D_{\alpha}\overline{D}_{\dot{\alpha}})\overline{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}\overline{\Xi} + \frac{1}{2}{\overline{D}}^2 D_{\alpha}\Xi\\
   &= D_{\alpha} X - \{D_{\alpha}, \overline{D}_{\dot{\alpha}}\}\overline{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}\overline{\Xi} + \frac{1}{2}D_{\alpha}{\overline{D}}^2 \overline{\Xi} + \frac{1}{2}([{\overline{D}}^2, D_{\alpha}] + D_{\alpha}{\overline{D}}^2)\Xi\\
   &= D_{\alpha}\left(X + \frac{1}{2}{\overline{D}}^2\overline{\Xi}\right) - \{D_{\alpha}, \overline{D}_{\dot{\alpha}}\}\overline{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}\overline{\Xi} + \frac{1}{2}(-2i\overline{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}\partial_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}})\Xi\\
   &= D_{\alpha}X' - i\partial_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}\overline{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}\overline{\Xi} - i \overline{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}\partial_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}\Xi\\
   &= D_{\alpha}X' - i\partial_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}\overline{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}\overline{\Xi} - i \partial_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}\overline{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}\Xi\\
   &= D_{\alpha}X' - i\partial_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}\overline{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}\overline{\Xi} 
\end{align}

whereas I also have

\begin{align}
\overline{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}\mathcal{J}_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}' &= \overline{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}\left(\mathcal{J}_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}} - i\partial_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}(\Xi-\overline{\Xi})\right)\\
&= D_{\alpha}X - i\partial_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}(\overline{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}\Xi - \overline{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}\overline{\Xi})\\
&= D_{\alpha}X -i\partial_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}\overline{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}\overline{\Xi}
\end{align}

One of these calculations has to be wrong: am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The improvement should preserve the Ferrara-Zumino equation, meaning that you expect to get
\begin{align}
{\overline{D}}^{\dot{\alpha}} \mathcal{J}'_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}
& = D_{\alpha}X'  \\
& = D_{\alpha} X + \frac{1}{2}D_{\alpha}{\overline{D}}^2\overline{\Xi}.
\end{align}

The only identity that you need is
$$
[ D_\alpha, \overline{D}^2 ] = -2i \partial_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}} \overline{D}^{\dot{\alpha}},
$$
then you can see right away that the second expression that you obtained is correct:
\begin{align}
{\overline{D}}^{\dot{\alpha}} \mathcal{J}'_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}
& = \ldots \\
& = D_{\alpha} X - i \partial_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}} \overline{D}^{\dot{\alpha}} \overline{\Xi}\\
& = D_{\alpha} X + \frac{1}{2}D_{\alpha}{\overline{D}}^2\overline{\Xi}.
\end{align}
There is certainly a mistake somewhere in your first derivation, even though I can't tell where it is.